# How to create an alias for a nested structure in C++?

Tags: c++, structure, alias, typedef

I can't create an alias for a nested structure in C++. Assume that we have this code below. Now, how to create an alias for `struct Score` using `typedef` or etc?

```
struct Information
{
    struct Score
    {
        struct Score *link;
        float src;

    } *src;
};
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". These are 2 different languages. Please pick the language you are using and you have a question about.

Comment: `in C/C++` there is no such language. There is no "C/C++". There is C, there is C++, as distinct languages. Do you want to write it in C or in C++? `to allocate some memory` Do you want to create a type alias or allocate some memory? How does creating a type alias is related to allocating memory and is related to "making a linked list"?

Comment: Have you read about typedef? Why do you assume that it works different on nested structs?

Comment: Are you simply looking for `using InfoScore = Information::Score` or `typedef Information::Score InfoScore`?

Comment: I removed the C tag because you must be asking about C++. In C, after the code shown, `struct Score` is usable as a complete type. In C++, it is not; you would have to use `Information::Score`. In the future, be aware of which language you are using (if you are using a compiler that supports multiple languages, be aware of which mode you are using it in) and do not tag questions with both C and C++ tags unless you are asking a question that involves both languages.

Comment: Additionally, when you have a problem like “I can’t create an alias for a nested structure,” explain or show what you mean, such as showing an attempt to use `typedef` that fails, along with the error message that results.

Comment: @Gerhardh: While I appreciate that posters create confusion by asking about C/C++, complaining that “there is no such thing as ‘C/C++’” comes off as rude, although you may not intend it to. The “/” punctuation is commonly used to mean “or”; asking about “C/C++” is asking about “C or C++”. It is not an indication there is one thing called “C/C++,” and posing the complaint in the way you do looks like an attempt to belittle the author. They should simply be told directly to ask about one language or the other, not confronted with this indirect criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `struct Score` only is declared inside `struct Information`, you won't be able to use it as its own entity. So break it out.

```
struct Score {
    struct Score *link;
    float src;
};

struct Information {
    struct Score *src;
};
```

Comment: In C++ you can use nested classes outside of the class they are declared in (as long as the visibility is not `private`).  The outer class simply works like a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `typedef` after the declaration of `struct Information`. There is no reason to define a new type inside the structure `Information`.

```
struct Information
{
    struct Score
    {
        struct Score *link;
        float src;
    } *src;
};

typedef struct Score score;
```